# Python/Pandas - Remove all columns from dataframe where > 50% of rows have the value 0

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with Python & Pandas. I would like to remove every column from my data frame where more than 50% of rows have the value 0 in that particular column.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# defining a dataframe
data = [['Alex',10, 173, 0, 4000],['Bob',12, 0, 0, 4000], ['Clarke',13, 0, 0, 0]]
# naming the columns
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age', 'Height', 'Score', 'Income'])

# printing the dataframe
print(df)
```

[image: Data Frame 1]

I managed to make a table that shows me how many rows have the value 0 for each column and the percentage. But I have the feeling I'm going down the wrong track. Can someone help?

```
# make a new dataframe and count the number of values = zero per column
zeroValues = df.eq(0).sum(axis=0)
zeroValues = zeroValues.to_frame()

# name the column
zeroValues.columns = ["# of zero values"]

# add a column that calculates the  percentage of values = zero
zeroValues["zeroValues %"] = ((zeroValues["# of zero values"] * 100) / 
len(df.index))

# print the result
print(zeroValues)
```

[image: Data Frame 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) for get percentage of `0` values first and then filter with `loc` - need all values less or equal with `0.5`:

```
zeroValues = df.eq(0).mean()
print (zeroValues)
Name      0.000000
Age       0.000000
Height    0.666667
Score     1.000000
Income    0.333333
dtype: float64

print (zeroValues <= 0.5)
Name       True
Age        True
Height    False
Score     False
Income     True
dtype: bool

df = df.loc[:, zeroValues <= 0.5]
print (df)
     Name  Age  Income
0    Alex   10    4000
1     Bob   12    4000
2  Clarke   13       0
```

One row solution:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.eq(0).mean().le(.5)]
print (df)
     Name  Age  Income
0    Alex   10    4000
1     Bob   12    4000
2  Clarke   13       0
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!